# Чем является слово "это" в выражении "Москва — это столица"?

Tags: языкознание

"Москва — это столица". Чем является "это"?

Answer (score 1):

Частица в роли связки.
Или по другой классификации, признающей связку как член предложения, - просто связка.

Comment: Так можно ее частицей, как "вот", считать или нет? Почему она нигде в перечне частиц не упоминается? Как быть в ЕГЭ?

Comment: Орфографический словарь (Лопатин)  
это, **частица и связка**  

Большой толковый словарь (Кузнецов)  
1. ЭТО. **частица.**  

Где ещё нигде "не упоминается"?  

Про ЕГЭ - не знаю, это к г. Фурсенко. 

Первую часть вопроса не совсем понял. При чем здесь "вот"?

Answer (score 0):

irina, В ЕГЭ вопросы, на которые нет однозначного ответа, стараются не включать.
behemothus! Не могли бы вы уточнить свой ответ. НАпример,  в данном предложении слово это является (какой частью речи) и выполняет роль (какого члена предложения).  Буду благодарна за четкий  ответ. И если можно - поясните о другой классификации... Или дайте ссылку. 
p.s. Рада, что случайно нашла этот форум. А нет ли информации об участниках? Кто отвечает? Просто любитель русского языка (это здорово!) или специалист-филолог, да еще  работающий по специальности. Это чтобы знать, кого о чем спросить можно.

Comment: Это - частица в роли связки. Или связка как самостоятельный член предложения - её таковым не все признают.   
"Другая классификация" - это как раз отголоски неоконченных споров о том, что считать "членами предложения".  
---
Касательно информации. Могу только о себе. Я никаким образом профессионально с русским языком - и вообще каким либо языком кроме языков программирования - не связан. Дилетантствую на радость любопытным.

Answer (score 0):

"Это столица" - составное именное сказуемое. Это - указательное слово, так же как "вот".